# postgreSQL "to_tsvector" is not working with "up" and "down" keyword

Tags: postgresql

I wonder why, in postgreSQL "to_tsvector" is not working with "down" and "up" keyword?

```
select to_tsvector('english', coalesce('down',''));
select to_tsvector('english', coalesce('up',''));
```

You'll notice that, we are getting the blank values. Is there any work around to search the "up" and "down" keyword with "to_tsvector"?

Answer (score 3):

These are stop words, words that are too common. Check the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS) to see how to change the list of stop words or even create your own dictionary.